# How to import Java class into Jython?

Tags: java, jython, wsadmin

I am writing a Jython script and like to use java in there. I started by just importing the java class which locates in the same directory as the jython script. but I am getting `ImportError: no module named Beach`.

I know the java class has to be in classpath. I am running jython script with WebSphere wsadmin.sh tool. I tried adding the path to classpath and exporting it before calling wsadmin.sh and it didn't help.

`export CLASSPATH=/home/xxx/bashdir/bin/`

I also tried calling it with wsadmin:

`wsadmin.sh -host hostname -wsadmin_classpath /home/xxx/bashDir/bin/`

still getting importError message.

I am not sure how to make the java class visible.

Comment: Sharing the actual `import` statement and the resulting exception would be helpful.  You should also share the value of `os.environ.get('CLASSPATH')` in the place where you do the `import`.

Comment: so here is my code:
#import Beach
#beach = Beach("Cocoa Beach","Cocoa Beach")
#beach.getName()
#print beach.getName()
from java.lang import Math
print Math.max(4,7)

from java.lang import ClassLoader
cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()
paths = map(lambda url: url.getFile(), cl.getURLs())
print paths

which works. if uncomment import I get:
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "<string>", line 5, in ?
ImportError: no module named Beach

Comment: Please edit the question. Comments are ill-suited for code.